# Getting substring of wchar_t[]

Tags: c++, string, wchar-t

I have:

```
wchar_t str[32];
```

I want to get a new substring of it, from place 0 to 5. How can I do it?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "get a new substring". You could set `str[5]` to `\0` if you want to shorten the string. You could copy the portion of interested and null terminate it if you want to keep the old string. You could pass pairs of pointers around to define the shorted range. It depends on your intent.

Comment: Consider using `std::wstring` instead of `wchar_t[]` for handling strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::basic_string` does have the constructor you're looking for:

```
constexpr basic_string( const CharT* s,
                        size_type count,
                        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So you may do:

```
std::wstring substr{str, 5};
```